# compare dates in results

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, date

I'm looking to compare the dates in the result set

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE foo=bar
```

Output

```
id, datetime, name
1, 2014-01-01 18:13:45, test 1
2, 2014-01-01 19:01:32, test 2
3, 2014-01-01 20:34:44, test 3
4, 2014-01-03 04:45:22, test 4
```

I would like to be able to tell between each record if the difference in time is less or more than 24 hours of the previous record.

Example:

```
1, 2014-01-01 18:13:45, test 1 <-- first record since the previous record
2, 2014-01-01 19:01:32, test 2 <-- second record was less than 24 hours since the previous record
3, 2014-01-01 20:34:44, test 3 <-- third record was less than 24 hours since the previous record
4, 2014-01-03 04:45:22, test 4 <-- fourth record was more than 24 hours since the previous record
```

thoughts?

Comment: try the `LAG()` function.

Comment: What determines the order of rows? id, datetime , name or something else? What if the difference is exactly 24h?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said by @ypercube, `lag()` will help.

```
select id,
       (d - lag) as lag, 
       case when (d - lag) < interval '24 hours' then false else true end as p
from (
      select id, 
             (datetime) as d, 
             lag(datetime) over (order by id) as lag 
      from lagtest
     ) as t;
```

For the first row no lag will be displayed.

Comment: or `over (order by datetime)`. It's not clear which of the two OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

[@Fabrizio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61101/3684) is basically right, but I would simplify:

```
SELECT id, datetime
       lag(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY id) + interval '1d' < datetime AS more_than_a_day
FROM   tbl;
```

There is no need for a subquery or even a `CASE` statement.